# Nested Array How to read subarray data?

Tags: arrays, nested

Here is my nested full array data. But how can I get Items data separately?

```
(
    {
    AID = 1;
    ASID = 2;
    IsMulti = 0;
    Items =         (
                    {
            ASDID = 5;
            DetailAR = A;
            DetailEN = A;
        },
                    {
            ASDID = 6;
            DetailAR = B;
            DetailEN = B;
        },
                    {
            ASDID = 7;
            DetailAR = C;
            DetailEN = C;
        },
                    {
            ASDID = 8;
            DetailAR = D;
            DetailEN = D;
        }
    );
    SpecAR = "Location Specs 2";
    SpecEN = "Location Specs 2";
  }
)
```

Comment: Show some code how the array is created, to see also what language you're talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an `NSArray` instance containing a single `NSDictionary` instance.

Each `NSDictionary` can be retrieved using:

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in array) {
```

Each dictionary contains many different items, keyed on their name:

```
    NSNumber *aid = dict[@"AID"];
    NSArray *items = dict[@"Items"];
```

The `Items` array is an array of dictionaries:

```
    for (NSDictionary *item in items) {
        NSNumber *asid = item[@"ASID"];
        NSString *detailAR = item[@"DetailAR"];
    }
}
```

All items are objects as Objective-C collection classes can only hold objects.  So numbers are `NSNumber` instances, strings are `NSString`, arrays are `NSArray` and dictionaries are `NSDictionary`.

Comment: Thanks for great help.